# Commit made by mistake on develop, unable to do a pull request

Tags: git, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

We have a rule that prevent us from commiting directly on `develop` without doing a pull request.

After having created my branch, I did not see that I forgot to switch to it, so I worked and made one commit on my local develop.

The issue that I've now is that I cannot push, and I cannot do a pull request.

What would you advice me to retrieve the changes,put them on the branch and cancel my commit?

We use bitbucket, visual studio, sourcetree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This script will create a branch from the last expected commit on `develop`, move your new commit over to the new branch and then remove the commit from `develop`.

You can rename `your-feature-branch` as needed.

```
git checkout develop
git branch your-feature-branch HEAD~1
git checkout your-feature-branch
git rebase develop
git checkout develop
git reset --hard HEAD
```

EDIT: `git rebase master` should be `git rebase develop`

Comment: Nice, when you do the `git rebase master`, does it have something to do with the `master` branch, or nothing at all?

Comment: Sorry, that should have been `git rebase develop`!

Comment: @J4N what makes you think ‘master‘ would be involved?

Comment: @EdmundDipple Thanks for the edit, make much sense now :). I'm not that familiar of the rebase command.